# How to do a stratified nonparametric test?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, stratification

I'm trying to use the "coin" (conditional inference) package to perform a stratified nonparametric test for difference in distribution (for count data).

I tried a stratified Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon rank sum test, which I think is called the van Elteren test:

```
wilcox_test(count ~ factor_of_interest | confounding_factor)
```

I also tried to do a stratified permutation test:

```
oneway_test(count ~ factor_of_interest | confounding_factor, distribution=approximate(B=10000))
```

**The problem is I can't find anywhere how the stratified version of these tests are performed, even in theory. Does anyone know? For example, is a p-value calculated for each stratum and then the p-values combined (say, using Fisher's method)?**

By the way, the wilcox_test gave the following result:

```
Asymptotic Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney Test
data:  count by factor_of_interest
        stratified by confounding_factor 
Z = 2.1462, p-value = 0.03186 
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
```

Why would a nonparametric test like the Wilcoxon give a Z score?

Comment: With respect to your final (minor) question - the asymptotic distribution of the Wilcoxon test statistic is Normal, and the Z score is calculated on the basis of that asymptotic distribution.

Comment: The test in itself is described in the online supplement to https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/suppl/10.1161/CIRCULATIONAHA.106.613638 by well-renowned statisticans Lisa LaVange and Gary Koch.
You can download it in a word document. Hope this is helpful. /Magnus